# Error in rendering in VueJS and Laravel mix

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-mix

I am having an error when I load the page the first time.

I have the following code in that component.

```
<router-link
    :to="{
        name: 'play',
        params: { token: this.$route.params.token,
                  id: user.id }
        }"
    target="_blank"
    >
        <button class="btn btn-warning fz-btn-play">
             <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
        </button>
</router-link>
```

when page loads first-time user.id is giving error because when it loads user variable is null.
error is  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null`

then I run created() method:

```
created() {
   axios.get("/api/getUser").then((response) => {
       this.user = response.data;
   });
},
```

when page is fully loaded it is working fine but the error is showing in console how to remove this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `v-if` on your `router-link`

```
<router-link
    v-if="user" //use user as v-if
    :to="{
        name: 'play',
        params: { token: this.$route.params.token,
                  id: user.id }
        }"
    target="_blank"
    >
        <button class="btn btn-warning fz-btn-play">
             <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
        </button>
</router-link>
```

This will prevent the error you are facing.